# CSS background image and default background?

Tags: background, background-image, css

I have a div which got an background color and an image (with transparent background)

I need a different background color on the div by default (white) and another color as background for the transparent image.

How can i solve this problem?

I have set the background like this by now:

```
background: rgb(0,0,255) url(images/trans.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
```

So when repeating stops I would need another background color.

I thought about a gradient as background but I do not know how to do this with a transition at a fixed pixel pos (works with %)

[here i got the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8x9k/)

Comment: Provide a JsFiddle link and your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write pixels instead of percentages:
UPDATE: closer example with the solid color:

```
background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat-x 0 0, -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0,0,255) 0px, rgb(0,0,255) 154px, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 155px, rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 300px);

background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat-x 0 0, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0px,rgb(0,0,255)),color-stop(154px,rgb(0,0,255)),color-stop(155px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)), color-stop(300px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5)));

background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat-x 0 0, -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0,0,255) 0px,rgb(0,0,255) 155px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 155px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 300px);

background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat-x 0 0, -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0,0,255) 0px,rgb(0,0,255) 154px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 155px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 300px);

background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat-x 0 0, -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(0,0,255) 0px,rgb(0,0,255) 154px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 155px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 300px);

background: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png) repeat-x 0 0, linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(0,0,255) 0px,rgb(0,0,255) 154px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 155px,rgba(255,255,255,0.5) 300px);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pBVsD/12/

Comment: I did not mean to make the gradient transparent, its the image that is  transparent and you see the gradient through the image, see my fiddle

Comment: Well, it was only an example. You can use a solid colour gradient. The thing is that you can use pixels for specify your gradient size

Comment: i understand, but every time I try to add an gradient the image gets lost. if you could provide me a fix for my fiddle it would be awesome. tried multiple (will add one of my tries as fiddle above)

Comment: Check it now, it is the same but with your rgb(0,0,255) color.

Comment: You lost your image because in my first example the gradient was before of the image. If you change the order, like in this update, the image will appear over the gradient.

Comment: this works like charm! thanks! my mistake was i had the gradient in front of the url...

Comment: The reason why the order matters is because:  If you use a gradient and an image you are using two different backgrounds at the same time. That's a new feature of CSS3, and it is not the same that specify a colour and image on the same one. If you realize it, you separe them with a coma (wich you don't do with the color).   
When using multiple backgrounds, they are displayed from upper to lower place in the order you write them, and you can use the number you want.